# ufw not working

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

```
ufw allow 11963/tcp
ufw reload
ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
11963/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
11963/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

root@something# sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3115/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      885/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12798         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      299986/cardano-node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12788         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      299986/cardano-node
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      885/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

and its not there, confirmed if i try a site like https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ or http://port.ping.pe/ please help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

You've used UFW to allow the port to listen, but you haven't initiated listening on the port, install netcat if you don't already have it, and try:

```
nc -l 11963
```

Comment: i have installed netcat and run nc -l 11963 but it looks like it is stuck.

Comment: nc -l 11963
я       **

Comment: @GeorgeBosancu after starting the `nc` command in one terminal, open another terminal and run your original `netstat` command

Comment: thank you. that helped me restore the connection. It was a problem with a inbound rule.